# "Div load" CSS animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, animation

I'm making an iOS app through Cordova that mimics a one-page native app.

I'm using PageTransitions.js and it uses divs as full pages (similar to jQuery mobile) to simulate smooth page transitions. With it, I'm using jQuery onClick functions to fire css animations.

My question is: Is there a way to delay css animations from playing until the device focuses on the div in which they're contained? I'd like to play these animations on div load to give layers to the page rather than it looking like a static webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite easily; without your code I'm just going to provide some pseudocode.

For your css:

```
#some-id.active .some-class {
  /*do some animation or other */
}
```

and do a javascript something like this:

```
// depending on your situation and other scripts you are using
// you'll probably want to wrap it jQuery closure to make sure
// that $ is jQuery.
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#some-id').onClick( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active'); // depending on setup you may want to remove this from other selectors when adding it to the current one.
  }
}
```